# На Ubuntu 14.04 LTS что то работает как DHCP-сервер. Как это что-то найти и настроить?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp

Изучал DHCP-сервер.Ввел
sudo apt install dhcp3-server.

Был предложен к установке isc-dhcp-server, был установлен.

Был отконфигурирован ./etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:
INTERFACES="eth0"

Был отконфигурирован /etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf:

```
default-lease-time 7200;
max-lease-time 43200;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.0.100 192.168.0.200;
option routers 192.168.0.1;
option domain-name-server 192.168.0.1;
}
```

Сохранено.
sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
Но с сетевой карты eth0 выдавались ip 10.42.0.x
ОС была переустановленна. Был установлен и настроен DNS-сервер (bind9). DHCP-сервер не устанавливался. НО ip адреса 10.42.0.x раздаются.
Спасибо.

Comment: `$ sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 udp and port 67` — есть запросы и ответы? приведите их пример, пожалуйста. небольшой. прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: $ sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 udp and port 67 ввел. Команда в процессе выполнения уже минут 5, информацию не выводит.

Comment: судя по адресу, вы как-то врубили `sharing internet connection`

Comment: Т.к. о схеме сети не сказано ни слова, то можно предположить, что DHCP-сервер работает вообще не на этой машине. Исключено? Напишите, почему.

Comment: Pavel Gridin, вы скорее всего правы , я вспомнил что изменял в Сетевые соединения-> проводное соединение1- >способ настройки -> предоставить сеть другим компьютерам. Т.к. DHCP не хотел работать. Я тогда думал что он так должен работать. Подскажите а что выбрать в способе настройки для DHCP-сервера? Там есть варианты:  Автоматически (DHCP), Автоматически (DHCP только в ручную), Вручную, Только для локальной связи, Выключено.

Comment: Да, это sharing internet connection. Спасибо всем. Настраивать его не буду.